# Difference between kafka rest api and confulent rest proxy?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

is there any difference between kafka rest api and confulent rest proxy. Any advantage and disadvantage for both?

As i can see kafka provides rest API. so, why we use confulent rest api instead of Kafka rest API?

Comment: There is no REST API in Apache Kafka. Can you clarify what you are referring to?